# UIButton adjustsImageWhenHighlighted Property With Background Color

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton

I have a set of buttons on a view controller that are added to the .xib and their properties are adjusted programmatically.

The background color is set in code as follows and then when it is tapped I change the background color using a selector method.

in configureButtons method:

```
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(changeButtonBackGroundColor:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

which calls the following:

```
-(void) changeButtonBackGroundColor:(id) sender {
    [sender setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed: 199/255. green: 95/255. blue: 45/255. alpha:1.0]];
}
```

Adjusting the background when touched programmatically works fine when the "Highlight Adjusts Image" property is set to YES but it shows the white glow when touched as well as changing the background color.

I don't want to see the white highlight when the button is touched so I turned off the property.  This causes the background color change to stop working.

Is there a way to change the background color of a UIButton without also showing the white glowing highlight when touched?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using background images with particular color. In that case you can easily make use of `– setBackgroundImage:forState:` function. I think this will work even when `showsTouchWhenHighlighted` is set to NO.

Comment: I don't use images on the buttons at all.  I just change color and change them to round buttons programmatically.  From what I can tell it doesn't seem possible to get rid of the highlight/glow when touched without also getting rid of the ability to change background color.

Comment: @motionpotion I was suggesting you to use images. You just have to create the right colored image and use it in a much simpler manner.